# Why won't my Gemfile run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I am following the Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial, and am in [section 1.2.4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-bundler) of the tutorial

When setting up a Rails app it says to run these commands:

```
cd first_app_direcory
sublime Gemfile
bundle update
```

The `sublime Gemfile` command edits the Gemfile obviously, but when I try to run the command `bundle update` I get the following error:

```
bundle update
Gemfile syntax error:
ruby 2.0.0 
         ^
/home/cameron/ruby/ror/first_app/Gemfile:2:
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER,
expecting '('
ruby 2.0.0 
          ^
```

I took these two lines out of the gemfile, even though it says to include them. Also, I tried Ruby 1.9.3, and still got the same error message.

```
ruby 2.0.0 
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0
```

After taking these lines out, it worked. I am trying to get it to work with those lines in the gemfile though.  How can I do this?

This is the full Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby 2.0.0 
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :developent do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20',require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: you should have quotes aroud version '2.0.0'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have

```
ruby '2.0.0'
```

instead of

```
ruby 2.0.0
```

in your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need quotes around the 2.0.0.

Something like `ruby "2.0.0"`.